# Conda vs. Mamba Confusion - What should be used when building custom docker images

Tags: jupyter, conda, mamba

I am trying to build a custom Docker Image using `jupyter/datascience-notebook` which is based off of `jupyter/base-notebook`

I can see that mamba was used to install/configure conda environment for jupyter.

Below is my Dockerfile (the portion which the question is about)

```
#REF: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66547389

RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda create -n pypy pypy ipykernel -y
RUN /opt/conda/envs/pypy/bin/pypy -m ipykernel install --prefix=/opt/conda/ --name pypy3 --display-name="pypy3"

#-- INSTALL JUPYTERLAB PLUGINS --#
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab-git
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install -c conda-forge jupyter-resource-usage
```

My question - should I actually be using `mamba` instead of `/opt/conda/bin/conda` since Mamba is a wrapper on conda? Or, am I doing the right thing?

Regards,

Answer (score 9):

In terms of functionality, either `conda` or `mamba` should work. I'd generally choose `mamba` over `conda` as `mamba` is faster than `conda`, but some may prefer `conda` as it is a more mature project.

`conda` is implemented in python, and therefore is not the fastest implementation possible. `mamba` is not a wrapper on conda, but a partial re-implementation that is focused on performance. `mamba` is written in C++, does parallel downloading of repository data and package files using multi-threading, and utilizes libsolv for much faster dependency solving. `mamba` utilities some of the `conda` code base for tasks that are not critical to performance and therefore `mamba` has a dependency on `python`.

Another option is `micromamba`, which is a purely C++ re-implementation of `conda` and does not have a dependency on `python`. If you are creating a new image from scratch and you do not need `python` in your image, then you should use `micromamba` to keep your resulting image small. The image [mambaorg/micromamba](https://hub.docker.com/r/mambaorg/micromamba) is a good starting point (full disclosure, I am the lead maintainer of this image).

As of March 16, 2022, it is possible to [use mamba's solver from within conda](https://conda.github.io/conda-libmamba-solver/getting-started/).

Comment: hello dear Will - well its somewhat confusing i just read this article 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421163/anaconda-vs-miniconda
 and i just got to know that mamba exists - i am a bit confused. Should i install this now!? plz help and adviced - btw i am on endeavourOS