# Installing mamba on a machine with conda

Tags: python, conda, mamba

I dont know if I have missed it, but this is not clear to me. I already have miniconda on my machine and I want now to install mamba. How this should be done please, I am  supposed to download/run the correct mambaforge installer? Does this co-exist happily side by side with conda or you are supposed to have just one of them on your system. Doing something like `conda install mamba` is not recommended

Comment: I'd recommend just installing mambaforge from https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge. In the environments you create with that you can use conda or mamba as necessary.

Comment: @MattPitkin maybe you should be more specific; your recommendation is to remove miniconda and have only mambaforge installed?

Comment: Thanks Matt, but Im confused because mamba should go in the base environment. This is where also conda goes

Comment: @FlyingTeller yes, I'd suggest removing miniconda and just having mambaforge as a direct replacement

Comment: a, ok, thanks Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mamba is a replacement conda package manager. They do not co-exist happily as they both rely on a base environment for their dependencies. The recommended way is to install mambaforge or micromamba separately as a replacement.

documentation for Mamba:
https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/mamba-installation.html

documentation for Micromamba: https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/micromamba-installation.html

Comment: It is nice to have options but doesnt this cause a fragmented landscape? So, we now have three package managers, pip, conda, mamba. Why not discontinuing conda and switch to mamba since the latter is better, something similar to python 2.7 and 3+

Comment: @Aenaon I have added a link that have related information. 
Mamba project rewritten some parts of conda code  in c++ for performance improvement but it still relies on conda-forge channel as a package repository. 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72959278/2423830)

Comment: @Aenaon the fragmentation is at the channel level, not the front-end (Conda and Mamba are interchangeable). Anaconda could easily build a copy of Mamba and distribute it from the `defaults` channels. The fragmentation is because Conda Forge is not compatible with the `defaults` channels due to uncoordinated build stacks, which lead to incompatible ABIs. There were attempts to coordinate it in the past, but once it was clear Conda Forge could build everything, coordinating epochs were abandoned. Anyway, Conda now uses Mamba solver by default, so speed-wise the difference is trivial.

Answer (score 15):

Mamba can *theoretically* be added to any install, but is no longer recommended.<sup>**1**</sup> Since Mamba is only distributed through Conda Forge, one must convert **base** to having the `conda-forge` channel prioritized. Be aware that this is generally incompatible with Anaconda **base**<sup>**1**</sup>, but can work fine with Miniconda **base**.

Essentially,

```bash
## prioritize 'conda-forge' channel
conda config --add channels conda-forge

## update existing packages to use 'conda-forge' channel
conda update -n base --all

## install 'mamba'
conda install -n base mamba
```

Now you can use `mamba` instead of `conda`.

---

<sub>**[1]:** Mamba developers recommend [installing Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge?#miniforge) as a **base**, since it prioritizes `conda-forge` channel by default.</sub>

<sub>**[2]:** The need to prioritize `conda-forge` channel is effectively incompatible with the Anaconda **base** because the combination of a large environment (Anaconda) and plus a larger package search space (Conda Forge) make the solution space enormous. Basically every question on SO about things taking infinitely long to solve is really about this. If you are starting from Anaconda **base** you'll want to first gut out the **base** environment to be minimal (remove the `anaconda` package).</sub>